# Two-lined brace in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking, nodes, scaling, node-connections

I want to produce a timeline in the `tikzpicture` environment that looks like this:

[image]

But my code, gives me the following:

[image]

So I need the brace around both lines of my node!

My code now looks as follows:

```
\begin{figure}\label{fig: timeline}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (11,0);
\foreach \x in {0.8,4,5.5,7,10.2}
\draw(\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm, -3pt);
\draw (0.8,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_0$};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_1$};
\draw (5.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$0$};
\draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_2$};
\draw (10.2,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_3$};
\draw (2.35,0) node[above=6pt, align=center] {(estimation \\ window]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\mytab}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (11,0);
\foreach \x in {0.8,4,5.5,7,10.2}
\draw(\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm, -3pt);
\draw (0.8,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_0$};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_1$};
\draw (5.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$0$};
\draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_2$};
\draw (10.2,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_3$};
\draw (2.35,0) node[above=6pt, align=center] {
                        $\left(\mytab{estimation \\ window}\right]$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

not elegant, but it works

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\label{fig: timeline} \begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture} \draw (0,0) -- (11,0); \foreach \x in {0.8,4,5.5,7,10.2} \draw(\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm, -3pt); \draw (0.8,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_0$}; \draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_1$}; \draw (5.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$0$}; \draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_2$}; \draw (10.2,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_3$}; \draw (2.35,0) node[above=6pt, align=center] {$\left(\parbox{0.62in}{estimation \ window}\right]$}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{center} \end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather than relying on the width of the parbox, perhaps a tabular would be more robust? `\(\left(\begin{tabular}{c}estimation\\window\end{tabular}\right]\)`

Comment: yup, that's better